# String producer on third-party constructor parameter

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm using a third party library. I'm using a constructor with one string parameter of class `SampleClass`:

```
public SampleClass(String apiKey) {...}
```

Then on my classes I'm injecting a `SampleClass` on a field:

```
public MyClass {
    @Inject private SampleClass sc;

    public MyClass() { ... }
```

I've created a String producer in order to get the String Api Key from OS environment variables:

```
public class SettingsPropertiesProducer {

    @Produces @com.living.commty.boot.cdi.qualifiers.ApiKey
    public String getApiKey()
    {
        return System.getenv(...
    }
}
```

How could I bind or link this producer to the first string parameter of `SomeClass(String apiKey)` constructor?

Comment: What is @com.living.commty.boot.cdi.qualifiers.ApiKey? Is it a qualifier? Post full your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another producer for your Sample class

```
public class SampleClassFactory {
     @Produces 
     public SampleClass getSampleClass(@Inject @ApiKey final String apiKey) {
        return new SampleClass(apiKey);
    }
}
```

If you're SampleClass has a no-arg constructor, you might have a conflict when injecting and you may need to create an additional qualifier to the SampleClass producer